# How to properly recognize a session id generated by drupal?

Tags: 8, sessions

I'm storing stuff in a session that is sometimes handled by drupal. The session id is passed forward to another service, which checks back to the original server to get the session data.

When the session id is generated by drupal, i want to recognize it so i can include the drupal bootstrap instead of creating a normal php session. What would be a proper way to recognize drupal session ids ?

Is there a way to make it more specific, like change the sessionid myself ?

Comment: "which is invalid in php" - false. Drupal *is written in PHP* so if it was invalid, Drupal would not be able to do it.

Comment: Yeah, the session ID is a _string_. `-` is not an invalid character for a string

Comment: I'd dig into includes/session.inc and see exactly how Drupal internally recognizes the id. I'd do it myself and post an answer, but don't have time ATM.

Comment: sorry guys - the _ is an invalid character in a php sessionid, as used by the default php session handling. Its not just a string. drupal overwrites the default handling. use the drupal id to create a default session and php will barf `Warning: session_start() [function.session-start]: The session id is too long or contains illegal characters, valid characters are a-z, A-Z, 0-9 and '-,' ... anyway, thats not really answering anything, is it.

Comment: The session ID is generated using `drupal_random_key()`, in `drupal_session_initialize()` and other functions. Drupal does no special processing of the session ID, and definitely nothing to do with manipulating underscores in the string. As @Letharion said you can see all of that in includes/session.inc. The file's only a few hundred lines long, very easy to understand

Comment: crossposting :-) Yes, its using drupal_random_key(). forget about the underscores, its not part of the question. the question is: how can i properly recognize drupal ids, or let drupal generate recognizable session ids, without hacking core.

Comment: Ah ok that makes sense ;)

Comment: Well, even though the question got downvoted, I'm glad I got an answer ... exactly what i needed to know; thanks Clive !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Drupal will let you override the default session handler using the `session_inc` variable. This is what Drupal actually uses to bootstrap the session:

```
require_once DRUPAL_ROOT . '/' . variable_get('session_inc', 'includes/session.inc');
```

So to replace that with your own, set the variable to your own path:

```
variable_set('session_inc', 'sites/all/modules/MYMODULE/session.inc');
```

And re-implement the functions from the core session.inc in your custom file, making changes where necessary.

Answer (score 0):

You can get seesion id by calling `session_id()` function.
For session name you can use `session_name()`.

Comment: Yes - these are php functions (the question was how I can recognize if they were generated by drupal .. it has slightly different ids)